# Does the routing paths order matter in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

I'm trying to make a router for one of my components, but it is not working as expected.

Initially it was working fine, but I had to add another route to decide which mat-tab would be open when redirecting. I added the second route like that, but for some reason the third one stopped working even though the first two were working fine.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ActionComponent } from './action.component';
import { ActionResolver } from './action.resolver';
import { ACTION_RESULT_ROUTES } from './result/action-result.routes';

export const ACTION_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: ActionComponent, resolve: { action: ActionResolver } },
  { path: ':id/:tab', component: ActionComponent, resolve: { action: ActionResolver } },
  {
    path: 'action-result',
    children: ACTION_RESULT_ROUTES,
  },
];
```

I got a pretty large error when trying the third route, but it starts like this:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'null' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

Just in case, I tried to reorder it and all three were working fine when I did it like this:

```
export const ACTION_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: ActionComponent, resolve: { action: ActionResolver } },
  {
    path: 'action-result',
    children: ACTION_RESULT_ROUTES,
  },
  { path: ':id/:tab', component: ActionComponent, resolve: { action: ActionResolver } },
];
```

Can anyone tell me why it works like that?

**Edit:** Added the ACTION_RESULT_ROUTES for clarification

```
export const ACTION_RESULT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: ActionResultComponent, resolve: { result: ActionResultResolver } },
];
```

Comment: how you access third route in your url ?

Comment: @GRD `action-result/XX` (xx being the ID number), the route is just like the first one which uses a ID, but it leads to a different component and uses a different resolver, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Angular:

> "The order of routes is important because the Router uses a
> first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific
> routes should be placed above less specific routes."

It is recommended to have static routes first, therefore your `action-result` path should go first, followed by the `:id/:tab` path then `:id` path last. If you have a wildcard route, it should always be the last route in your array.

The reason behind this logic is that if you had the `:id` path above the `action-result` path, angular would use the word 'action-result' as the id in the `:id` path.
Similarly if you had the `:id` path above the `:id/:tab` path, angular would use the words id/tab as the id in the `:id` path.

So, a rule of thumb is to always put your static routes first, then your dynamic routes from the most specific to the least specific followed by your wildcard route at the end.
E. G.

- PATH1
- PATH2
- PATH3/:USER/:ROLE/:PAGE
- PATH4/:SITE/:ID
- PATH5:/ID
- Wildcard route (*)